# Parsing text in Julia- Invalid ascii sequence

Tags: file, parsing, ascii, julia

I'm trying to format a data file so that my other program will properly handle it. I am trying to handle the following data and I am getting a very weird error that I can't seem to put my finger on.

https://snap.stanford.edu/data/wiki-RfA.html

I am trying to format the data as [SRC TGT VOT], so I'd like the first two lines of my output file to be

```
1 2 1
3 2 1
```

because user 1 (stored in dictionary of users first) votes for user 2 with VOT 1 and then user 3 votes for user 2 with VOT 1. My problem is that when I try to run my code below, I always end up getting a very strange "invalid ascii sequence" error- can anyone help me identify the issue or perhaps find a way around this? It'd obviously be best if I could learn what I am doing wrong. Thank you! 
Note, I understand that this is a bit specific of a question and I appreciate any help- I'm sort of baffled by this error and don't know how to resolve it at the moment.

```
f=open("original_vote_data.txt") #this is the file linked above
arr=readlines(f)
i=edge_count=src=tgt=vot=1
dict=Dict{ASCIIString, Int64}()
edges=["" for k=1:198275]
while i<1586200
    src_temp=(arr[i])[5:end-2]
    if (haskey(dict, src_temp)) 
        new_src= dict[src_temp]
    else 
        dict[src_temp]=src
        new_src=src
        src=src+1
    end
    tgt_temp=(arr[i+1])[5:end-2]
    if (haskey(dict, tgt_temp)) 
        new_tgt= dict[tgt_temp]
    else 
        dict[tgt_temp]=tgt
        new_tgt=tgt
        tgt=tgt+1
    end
    vot_temp=(arr[i+2])[5]
    edges[edge_count]=string(new_src)* " " * string(new_tgt)* " " *string(vot_temp)
    edge_count=edge_count+1
    i=i+8
end
```

Comment: I haven't looked closely at this, but my hunch is in the fourth line: `dict=Dict{ASCIIString, Int64}`.  Is this where the user names go?  And are the user names sometimes unicode?  Perhaps try `Dict{UTF8String, Int64}`. Similarly for edges — instead try `edges=Array(UTF8String,198275)`.

Comment: Thank you! Long delay on my end but I will try this out tomorrow. Hopefully you're right!

Comment: @user3587051 Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go - I'll write up my comment as an answer since it seems to have solved the question.

My hunch that the error stemmed from the fourth line (`dict=Dict{ASCIIString, Int64}`) was based on the fact that ASCIIStrings will error if you try to store non-ASCII characters in them.   Since this file is coming from an international site, it's not unlikely that there are users with unicode characters in their names (or elsewhere in the data).  So the simple fix is to change all instances of `ASCIIString` to `UTF8String`.

Just to make this answer a bit more complete, I downloaded the file and tried running the program.  The simplest way to debug this is to run the script at top-level in the REPL and then inspect the program state after the error.  After the error is thrown, `i==3017`.  Now just try running each line of the while loop incrementally.  You'll quickly see that line 3017 contains `"SRC:Guðsþegn\n"` — unicode, as I suspected.  When you try to create a new entry in `dict` with that as the key, the error should have a backtrace to [`setindex!` in dict.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/6e3d0b8b756dba7566babe14498631a0f8ed213f/base/dict.jl#L547), where you'll see that it's trying to convert the key (a UTF8String) to an ASCIIString.  So changing the dictionary type to have UTF8String keys solves the problem.

As it turns out, the edges array only contains strings of three integers (or sometimes a hyphen), so the ASCIIString there is ok, but still a little dangerous.  I'd probably store that information in a more dedicated array of ints instead of converting it to a space-separated string: you know the first two elements in the string are ints, but the last element is unvalidated text from the file itself… which may be unicode or a space itself (which could mess up processing down the line).